# Orchard cms workflow not showing send mail node

Tags: workflow, orchardcms

In Orchard CMS I am trying to send email after form is submitted, but there is no Send Email node in workflows.  I added Messaging module and Email Messaging module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to enable the Email Workflows Activities feature to be able to add Send Email node to your workflows.